# Setup Oracle Help Web(OHW) for Java applications

Tags: java

I need to setup an online help system for my Java application. Its totally swing based. On searching I found OHW is good.

Can anyone suggest me how to configure or setup OJW to an Java application. Any tutorial link will be very useful.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I know I am not answering your question.. but we designed a help system for our java swing application as well. We felt html files were the best. The kind that has iframes and a small java script on the index page that will load the center frame based on a parameter you set in the URL. You can make context sensitive help with this. Also, there is a free editor out there for non-commercial application called helpndoc. Pretty good HTML editor and will generate the HTML files and/or chm file for you. http://www.helpndoc.com/

Also, if your java app is for a windows only system then you can go with just a chm file. You can open a chm file to show context sensitive help as well. The helpndoc tutorial shows you how.

If its cross platform then html files are the best.